# thead repetition using css

Tags: html, css, printing, media-queries

I am using css media query for printing header on every page, it works well but as I increase column greater than two or increase font-size in last column or set height, it does not work i.e it is not printed on all pages.

I'm unable to understand what was going wrong. I want to complete it using table structure not by using div `position:fixed`. Please check below code or please suggest any other code for accomplishing this task.

Thanks in advance.

```
<!–-css code -–>
<style>
    @media print {
        thead { display: table-header-group;}
    }
</style>
<!–-css code- –> 

<!–-html code -–>
<table id=”tbl_head” width=”100%”>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style=”border-bottom:2px solid #999;”>
                <!--Customize Header -->
                <table width="100%">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td colspan="3">
                        <h4 style="text-align: center; font-weight: normal; background: #ccc none repeat scroll 0% 0%; font-size: 16px; padding: 8px 0px; margin: 2px 0 0 0; border: 1px solid #000;">FULLY COMPUTERISED LAB</h4>
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td style="text-align:left;">
                        <span style="text-align: left;margin-bottom: 0px;font-size: 22px;font-weight:bold">Test</span>
                        <span style="font-size: 12px;margin-top: 5px">Test Centre</span>
                      </td>
                      <td style="text-align:left;">
                        <span style="font-size:18px;margin-bottom: 2px;margin-top: 2px">Dr. sharma</span>
                        <span style="margin-top:2px">M.D.</span>
                      </td>
                      <td style="text-align:left;">
                        <span style="font-size:10px"><b>Address</b></span>
                        <span style="font-size:10px"><b>Phone: 0731-787878, Mobile: </b></span> 
                        <span style="font-size:10px"><b>Email: example2514@gmail.com</b></span>
                        <span style="font-size:10px"><b>Time: 7:30am to 10pm; Sunday 8am to 1pm</b></span>
                      </td> 
                  </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table> 
            <!--Customize Header -->
          </th>
         </tr>
        </thead>
       <!--thead tag close -->
        <tbody>
          <tr>
             <td>
                   <!-- some other code here -->
             </td>
           </tr>
         </tbody>
        </table>
    <!–-html code -–>
```

Comment: Is this an email? if not then you should not be using the table in the way you are.  Tables are for tabular data only and should not be used for layout purposes.  Especially the way you have done with a nested table in the header

Comment: @Pete,it is not an email.It is just HTML,actually i have used table or nested table because of only print repetition purpose.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this example will help you. With it you can put your text in whatever amount of independent columns!
http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_column-count

```
.class name or #id name {
 -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
 -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
 column-count: 3;
}
```